Is it possible to create callback xinclude statements from a "passed" directory?
I have a generic XML that I want to regionalize while keeping the overall structure the same across regions. Assume the region specific parts are in correspondingly named sibling directories of the generic xml directory. In my non-simplified situation, the region-specific includes are themselves in sub-includes (e.g. Snippet1_1_2.xml etc), but I assume this does not make a fundamental difference since xinclude is able to resolve recursive includes in principle.
<!-- GenericMasterConfig.xml -->
<GenericMasterConfig>
  <xi:include href="Snippet1.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="Snippet2.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="../&RegionSpecificIncludeDir;/RegionSpecific_Snippet3.xml">
    <xi:fallback>This region has no snippet 3!</xi:fallback>
  </xi:include>
  <xi:include href="Snippet4.xml"/>
  <!-- etc. -->
</GenericMasterConfig>

<!-- RegionSpecificMasterConfig.xml (omitting entity block details) -->
<!-- ... -->
<!ENTITY RegionSpecificIncludeDir "MyRegion"> <!-- alternative? -->
<!-- ... -->
<RegionSpecificMasterConfig>
  <xi:include href="../generic/GenericMasterConfig.xml"/>
</RegionSpecificMasterConfig>

<!-- MyRegion/RegionSpecific_Snippet3.xml -->
<SubConfig>
  <xi:include href="../generic/Snippet_3_1.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="RegionSpecificSnippet_3_2.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="../generic/Snippet_3_3.xml"/>
<SubConfig>

I did not get my first idea based on entities in the (top level) region specific files to work, xmllint --xinclude gives me "parser error : Entity 'RegionSpecificIncludeDir' not defined".
Any suggestions?
edit: I guess it comes down to whether xinclude fully resolves the included file first, or "includes" it in a copy&paste manner and then continues resolving the complete document.

In case someone else has the same problem:
My XML contains "instructions" for some internal config processor. I created an "include instruction" with optional parameters (such as a callback include directory) as a workaround, because I could not get this mechanism to work with just XML, entities and xinclude.
